# Binance API call working fine on Console Application but not on WinForm c#

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await, synchronization

This is the Github Repository which I am using
https://github.com/ilkerulutas/BinanceSdk

The code is working fine on a console application but it takes too much time to get a response in windows form application.

```
//Async Method

public async Task<TimeResponse> Time()
    {
        return await SendRequest<TimeResponse>("time", ApiVersion.Version1, ApiMethodType.None, HttpMethod.Get);
    }

  //Sync Method

    public TimeResponse TimeSync() => Time().Result;
```

I am calling both but async method is giving status **WaitingForActivation** and Sync method is taking too much time to get response.

I am calling these 2 methods as

```
var timeResponseAsync = publicRestClient.Time();  //For Async
var timeResponseSync1 = publicRestClient.TimeSync();  // For Sync
```

Answer (score 2):

You are deadlocking your UI thread.

My guess would be that you are calling `TimeSync()` which then calls a `Task.Result`, which blocks the UI thread until the `Task` returned from `Time()` is finished.

As you have an `await` inside `Time()` which starts on the UI thread, the async callback once the request is complete will be scheduled to happen on the UI thread, but this UI thread is already blocked by waiting for the `Task.Result`. So therefore you are in a deadlocked situation.

Could you show how you are using `TimeSync` and why are you using a `Sync` method which then uses an `async` method. To properly fix it, you need to make everything up the call chain async and await the result!

One patch fix you can try is to do (this may or may not work, best case scenario it will still block the UI for the duration of the call):

```
public TimeResponse TimeSync() => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Time()).Result;
```