# How to Use Binance API in Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, synchronization

There is a [Github Repository of Binance API](https://github.com/ilkerulutas/BinanceSdk).

In Console Application C#, Can i use this API in windows form application or there will be some UI Thread Blocking Issue.

Comment: Why not simply give it a try? You can later ask precise questions on your own code that you struggle with?

Comment: Yeah i have given it a try, and i am stuck in deadlock situation now as its working fine on console application but no response in winform.

Comment: Haven't you already asked a similar question **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51943964/binance-api-call-working-fine-on-console-application-but-not-on-winform-c-sharp)** but this time worded it differently

Answer (score 3):

Of corse, [Repository](https://github.com/ilkerulutas/BinanceSdk/tree/master/M3C.Finance.Binance.Example) already contains console application example without any issue.
There are few steps how to use:

1. Provides both Async and Sync Methods
2. Added an Example Console App which contains all API calls.
3. Usage examples for each function can alse be found in the test project.
4. You need to enter your own Api Credentials in the App.config file of the test/example projects if needed.

Comment: Yes but i have to use this api in windows form

Comment: API has async method, so you need just implement windows forms for possibility to work with async method [Microsoft Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-implement-a-form-that-uses-a-background-operation)

Comment: Other worlds implement windows form which use Async API method as background operation